# 1950s short story featuring a debate about whether robots have souls

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots

I recall a short story, probably 1950s, where a corporation is engaged in the manfacture of humanoid robot servants, but finds its sales dropping off due to a campaign by a hellfire preacher, who maintains that it is immoral to manufacture creatures with no souls.

They challenge him to a theological debate with one of their robots. The preacher wins, and the robot is mocked by the audience. However, the preacher butts in and reveals that he is also a robot.

Ring any bells?

Comment: I would have thought the opposite, that it's immoral to manufacture robots **with** souls. If there were any way to tell if they had them or not. What is the question they are debating, whether robots have souls, or whether it is immoral to manufacture robots without souls?

Comment: I think it was on whether they had souls.

Comment: Was it in an anthology or a magazine?

Comment: Probably an anthology.

Comment: @user14111: substitute self-aware for soul and it is a real question being debate today.

Comment: This sounds like the sort of thing Asimov would have written in his US Robots stories, but I don't recall one involving a preacher.

Comment: This is a feature of the original robot story. Karl Capek's play _[R.U.R.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R.U.R.)_ but I don't have the text handy.

Comment: This has some similar elements to Asimov's [Evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidence_(short_story)), where a politician is accused of being a robot, a heckler challenges him and the politician punches him (which a robot couldn't do), but the speculation/twist is that maybe he could if the heckler were also a robot.

Comment: This reminds me a little of "In His Image" by Lloyd Biggle, Jr, included in the collection *The Metallic Muse*, but it is not a close enough match to write up as an answer

Comment: There was also *Soul of the Robot* by Barrington J. Bayley, following a robot that had a soul when this was almost universally accepted as impossible...

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for all the suggestions, but I've found it.

It was *Unknown Quantitity* by Peter Phillips (aka "At No Extra Cost") first published 1949 in *New Worlds #5* and anthologised elsewhere.